# Associate a file type with emacs/cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

I want to use Emacs as and editor and shell.
On Windows 7 I installed `cygwin` , X11 and emacs.
In terminal I added to `/etc/profile` file these lines:

```
XWin -multiwindow 2> /dev/null&
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sleep 1
emacs 2> /dev/null&
```

I created a shortcut that execute this command: `C:\rhcygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -`
Now every time I start that shortcut it starts `emacs`. No problem.
My goal is: associate some file types like `.txt` , `.csv` and etc with `emacs` in order when I start `foo.txt` it'll open in emacs.
When I tried to do it `'Set Associtation'` control it accepts only file name and it does not take '-'. Hence when I try to open `foo.txt` it does not work. I tried to create a shortcut to `mintty.exe` but it didn't work either.
Could someone help me to create association in order to start to `mintty.exe` but rather `mintty.exe` -  ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking my question off .
I realized that my problem is related to subshell issue ... when I try to invoke first cygwin, then emacs under it and etc.
I decided that I will not use much Windows Explorer but rather go directly to the file and open it. This way I don't need file association.
Please close my ticket.
Thanks